# AWS SSM Run command Output

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

How can we send the logs of an SSM document execution via Run command when the SSM DOCUMENT is executed through the Eventbridge rule schedule?

For ex; Running a simple Hello world script in linux and need the run command output for it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no log configuration in the EventBridge rule for any target type.

The logging will be configured on the Target, e.g. Lambda function. EventBridge will have an entry in CloudTrail but that doesn't provide any information about the output of the command executed.

> Running a simple Hello world script in linux and need the run command output for it

I tested this. There should be an entry in Systems Manager Run Command console with the Command-ID. Then you can use aws cli to check the command invocation details.

```
aws ssm get-command-invocation --command-id {command-id} --instance-id {instance-id}

{
   ...
   "StandardOutputContent": "Hello world!\n",
   ...
}
```

If you are using Run Command to execute a script, you can also upload the script output to CloudWatch logs or S3 bucket as part of the script.

Comment: But the problem is I am not able to push the output to cloudwatch logs . I am just using a shell script to print Hello world. For ex: action: run: Shellscript run command "print Hello world" , how can I push this output to cloudwatch logs ?